# Delete all entries from a table won't work

Tags: mysql, innodb

Anyone can tell me why this line won't work?
The table is like this: `id, playerId, points`.
`playerId` is a foreign key.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM `contestants`";   
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR:QUERY_FAILED timeset 13" . mysql_error());
```

Both commands

```
DELETE FROM `contestants`
```

and

```
TRUNCATE `contestants`
```

work from phpmyadmin.

Any ideas? Do you see a syntax error? The php log doesn't show an error.

Comment: An error message would be really, really helpful to those of us who would answer :)

Comment: "playerId is a foreign key" - probably because you have tables referencing those keys?

Comment: @kmfk Foreign keys can be deleted perfectly well. It's the PK that can't be deleted if an FK elsewhere refers to it, so "id" might be the issue. But there are many, many other things that could be wrong too - permissions, typo in the table name, connection not made, no database selected, trigger catching it and rolling back, etc. etc.

Comment: The player id refers to an id in another table called players. So that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that username/password you are using for your application has permissions to manipulate said database. Because if you can execute the query in SQL input box in PhpMyAdmin and not via PHP this to me suggest's that while you are in PhpMyAdmin its using default root no password or root/root login.

I had a similar problem what solved for me is going to phpmyadmin > selecting the said database > permissions > select my username scrolling to bottom and hitting Save.

For some reason eve tho my account had all roles for all DB i still had to do this.

In anycase i would run this just to be sure:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR username@localhost;
```